# Should I deploy a neutral app bundle or x86, x64, ARM separately?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store

When creating a release build for Windows 8 app, should I use a neutral appx?

[image]

Or should I use an app bundle with x86, x64, and ARM separately?

[image]

What exactly is the difference? Pros/Cons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your app is using any c++ dlls for example SQLite you need to deploy each version separately.  Otherwise you can release anycpu version.  Note in UWP app (win 10) there is no longer an any cpu option.

Comment: So if I'm not using any C++ DLLs, Any CPU would not make a difference compared to a separate x64/x86/ARM build?

Comment: I am deploying a UWP app in Win 10, and there IS a "Neutral, Release (Any CPU)" option. That's what led me to this question.